# What is $\frac{dw(z)}{dz}$ and what $\frac{d^2w(z)}{dz^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\zeta = \frac{1}{z}$ and $v(\zeta)=w(z)$. What is $\frac{dw(z)}{dz}$ and what $\frac{d^2w(z)}{dz^2}$?

I need a procedure how to get results.

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: What is $v(\zeta)$?

Comment: Is $z$ real?${}$

Comment: i know the result is $\frac{dw(z)}{dz} = -\frac{1}{z^2} \frac{dv(\zeta)}{d\zeta} = -\zeta^2 \frac{dv(\zeta)}{d\zeta}$ because $\frac{dw(z)}{dz} = \frac{dw(z)}{d\zeta} \cdot \frac{d\zeta}{dz}$

Comment: I didn't know how to solve the second part of my question, but I found out now :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v(\zeta)=v(1/z)=w(z)$ then $\frac{dw(z)}{dz}=\frac{dv(1/z)}{dz}$, so you can use the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule): $    (f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)\cdot g' $ to get:

$$
\frac{dw(z)}{dz}=\frac{dv(1/z)}{dz}=-\frac1{z^2}v'(1/z)=-\zeta^2\cdot v'(\zeta)
$$